How can I extract a Qlik app layout/structure as JSON directly from Qlik cloud?
What is the simplest way to get the structure/layout of my Qlik dashboards in the form JSON files in Qlik Cloud? So it should contain detailed informaions about visualizations & styles.
I can already extract it from the Qlik Sense Desktop Version with the script from How can i get a Qlik app layout as XML/JSON File?. But how do I extract the layout information directly from Qlik Cloud?
My script can already open the app.
(async () => {

  const { docMixin } = await import("enigma-mixin");
  const enigma = require('enigma.js');
  const schema = require('enigma.js/schemas/12.20.0.json');
  const WebSocket = require('ws');
  const fs = require('fs');

  require('dotenv').config();

  const QCS_HOST = process.env.QCS_HOST || 'host-id.de.qlikcloud.com';
  const QCS_API_KEY = process.env.QCS_API_KEY || 'my-API-Key';

  const appId = 'ee536af8-6e5a-4b97-b8af-8aedec556d10'; // App-ID anpassen
  const filePath = 'entities.json'; // Dateipfad für die gespeicherten Entitäten

  const session = enigma.create({
    schema,
    mixins: [...docMixin],
    url: `wss://${QCS_HOST}/app/${appId}`,
    createSocket: (url) => new WebSocket(url, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${QCS_API_KEY}` },
    }),
  });

  async function run() {
    try {
      const global = await session.open();
      console.log('Verbindung erfolgreich hergestellt');

      let doc;
      
      // Versuche, das Dokument zu öffnen
      try {
        doc = await global.openDoc(appId);
        console.log('Dokument erfolgreich geöffnet');
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === 1002) {
          // Fehler "App already open", wir holen die bereits geöffnete App
          console.log('Die App ist bereits geöffnet');
          doc = await global.getActiveDoc();
          console.log('Referenz zur bereits geöffneten App geholt');
        } else {
          throw error; // Anderen Fehler weitergeben
        }
      }

      // Abrufen der Entitäten
      const entities = await doc.mUnbuild();

      // Entitäten in eine Datei speichern
      saveEntitiesToFile(entities);

      await session.close();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Fehler während der Ausführung:', error);
    }
  }

  function saveEntitiesToFile(entities) {
    // Konvertierung der Entitäten in einen JSON-String mit Einrückung
    const entitiesJSON = JSON.stringify(entities, null, 2);

    // Schreiben der Entitäten in die Datei
    fs.writeFile(filePath, entitiesJSON, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Fehler beim Speichern der Entities:', err);
        return;
      }
      console.log('Entities erfolgreich gespeichert.');
    });
  }

run();
})();

Verbindung erfolgreich hergestellt
Dokument erfolgreich geöffnet
Fehler während der Ausführung: TypeError: obj.getParent is not a function
    at file:///c:/Users/j.stoeffler/Documents/git/BI_Migration/node_modules/enigma-mixin/dist/index.js:838:14
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (file:///c:/Users/j.stoeffler/Documents/git/BI_Migration/node_modules/enigma-mixin/dist/index.js:21:58)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)


enigma-mixin should work with SaaS as well. When you say that its working on Desktop, is with the same app or some other app? If its a different app then do you have any idea of what type of objects are used in the SaaS app? Ive made some tests against SaaS and it was working fine. Its possible that Qlik have added some new objects there that dont have the same structure as the other generic objects. Ill do few more tests today as well

Using Qlik-CLI might be easiest, depending on what you want to achieve and where/how you're running it. Particularly the app unbuild command that "Extracts generic objects, dimensions, measures, variables, reload script and connections from an app in an engine into separate json and yaml files".
